# Akka Streams for server streaming (gRPC, Scala)

Tags: scala, akka, grpc, akka-stream, akka-grpc

I am new to Akka Streams and gRPC, I am trying to build an endpoint where client sends a single request and the server sends multiple responses.

This is my protobuf

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "customer.service.proto";

service CustomerService {

  rpc CreateCustomer(CustomerRequest) returns (stream CustomerResponse) {}

}

message CustomerRequest {
  string customerId = 1;
  string customerName = 2;
}

message CustomerResponse {
  enum Status {
    No_Customer = 0;
    Creating_Customer = 1;
    Customer_Created = 2;
  }

  string customerId = 1;
  Status status = 2;
}
```

I am trying to achieve this by sending customer request then the server will first check and respond No_Customer then it will send Creating_Customer and finally server will say Customer_Created.

I have no idea where to start for it implementation, looked for hours but still clueless, I will be very thankful if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to start is the [Akka gRPC documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/index.html) and, in particular, the service [WalkThrough](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/server/walkthrough.html). It is pretty straightforward to get the samples working in a clean project.

The relevant server sample method is this:

```
override def itKeepsReplying(in: HelloRequest): Source[HelloReply, NotUsed] = {
  println(s"sayHello to ${in.name} with stream of chars...")
  Source(s"Hello, ${in.name}".toList).map(character => HelloReply(character.toString))
}
```

The problem is now to create a `Source` that returns the right results, but that depends on how you are planning to implement the server so it is difficult to answer. Check the [Akka Streams documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/index.html) for various options.

The client code is simpler, just call `runForeach` on the `Source` that gets returned by `CreateCustomer` as in the sample:

```
def runStreamingReplyExample(): Unit = {
  val responseStream = client.itKeepsReplying(HelloRequest("Alice"))
  val done: Future[Done] =
    responseStream.runForeach(reply => println(s"got streaming reply: ${reply.message}"))

  done.onComplete {
    case Success(_) =>
      println("streamingReply done")
    case Failure(e) =>
      println(s"Error streamingReply: $e")
  }
}
```